# FormatException string must be exactly one character long

Tags: c#, .net, string, formatexception

My code is

```
objVehicle.TaxAmount = CalculateTax_TaxableVeh(
     objVehicle.IsLogging,
     Convert.ToChar(objVehicle.CurrentWeightCategory),
     Convert.ToInt16(Session["FUM"]),
     Convert.ToInt16(Session["TAX_YEAR"]));
```

I am getting Formatexception '**String must be exactly one character long.**' at TAX_YEAR

Comment: I assume you dont get the error at `TAX_YEAR` but `Convert.ToChar(objVehicle.CurrentWeightCategory)`

Comment: As other stated, `objVehicle.CurrentWeightCategory` is not 1 char long. To confirm, try `objVehicle.CurrentWeightCategory.Substring(0,1)` and you will get no exception.

Comment: You should store those converted values in separate variables before you pass them to the method. Then you would notice at which line and with which value you actually get the exception. Since this method call is one statement you don't notice that `Convert.ToInt16(Session["TAX_YEAR"])` works without a problem but `Convert.ToChar(objVehicle.CurrentWeightCategory)` not.

Answer (score 3):

`string` can contains many characters but `char` stores a single character.

`Convert.ToChar()` tries to convert the input to one character. When the input is of type string and it contains more than one character you get the exception you have mentioned in the question.

You should check `objVehicle.CurrentWeightCategory`.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.